# setting disable_tcp_switch of pjsip_cfg_t on android

Tags: android, pjsip

we use pjsip in a mobile app that works both on iOS and on Android.

on iOS we can disable the switch to TCP by using:

```
pjsip_cfg()->endpt.disable_tcp_switch = PJ_TRUE;
```

however we cannot find a way to do this on Android.

how can we set this on Android?

Comment: Did you ever discovered the way to do this in android?